# Why is a public writable directory vulnerable?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, permissions, file-permissions

Just experimenting with stuff :)

I created a new directory and did chmod 777 (made it publicly writable)

Now suppose i don't have access to the server where this directory is. I tried the following:

1. file_put_content('http://myserver.com/writabledir/newfile.txt', "my newfile file contents"); (I am a PHP user). // didn't work as HTTP wrapper is not supported.
2. I used javascript to upload file to the same writable dir. I get a CORS error.

Now that i could not upload any file to this public writable directory. Could someone point out how can one misuse the public writable directories?

Comment: Because nothing should have any more privileges then exactly needed to work. If _any_ process on your server is compromised, they can write there. They shouldn't be able to. The question is not: "Why wouldn't I do this?". Start to think in: "Why would I need this?". Setting the proper owner & only giving that on write rights is a start, if you have multiple users & no spanning group read up on `setfacl`, and actually, start running `SELinux`.

Comment: @Wrikken I totally agree with you and that is what i would follow in the real world. The question comes out of curiosity and i am sure that there are some evil ways of taking advantage of such a setup. Just curious to know HOW its done.. I am really hungry for knowledge :) So just knowing that it should not be done is not enough for me.. I need an answer to the WHY.

Comment: See it like this: Apache is not supposed to write there, and won't unless you explicitly configure it to be able to, _IF_ it all works as intended. However, if an Apache exploit is found, you want to minimize the damage it can do. And that is assuming you own the whole server, if you're on shared hosting.. well.. anyone can do what they like there.

Comment: @LuckySoni I think you're getting confused a bit. You can't write to a file on a server using PHP's file_put_contents() or JavaScript. It needs to be something directly on the server, for example a PHP or Perl script, bash script, someone connected via SSH, etc. For example, if you are on a shared host, it may be possible for anyone else on the host to modify your files if they are world-writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone point out how can one misuse the public writable directories?

In and of itself? They can't misuse them. In conjunction with other features (or vulnerabilities), it makes exploitation *easier*.

That's the entire answer. We could dive into hypothetical scenarios and discuss various [threat models](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications), but ultimately, recommendations to make your publicly accessible directories read-only come from a position of "don't take unnecessary risks".

It's a strong position to be in.